# Does R have a priority queue like Java's PriorityQueue?

Tags: r, priority-queue

I am looking for a general purpose priority queue in `R`. Does R has any general purpose priority queue implementation (package) like Java `PriorityQueue` class or Python `heapq`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue for background reading in case anyone fancies implementing it

Comment: Doesn't look like much work, and it looks like it could be fun. Too bad you I have to go to Ikea today... ;)

Comment: I recall doing something like this with rredis only took an hour or so to throw together.

Comment: I've placed a bounty on this to see if anything has happened in the last 4 years.  This comment should also let people direct comments to me.

Comment: Hi @Joel, please see my answer below. There is now a liqueueR package on CRAN which does the job.

Answer (score 4):

I went ahead and implemented a basic queue as an R Reference Class. The details can be found [here](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2013/11/implementing-a-queue-as-a-reference-class/). It's been extended to handle a priority queue, as documented [here](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2013/11/deriving-a-priority-queue/).

The basic and priority queue implementations are now available as the [liqueueR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/liqueueR/index.html) package on CRAN, with a development version on [GitHub](https://github.com/DataWookie/liqueueR).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following [implementation from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Priority_queue#R), but beware that insertion takes O(n log n)

```
PriorityQueue <- function() {
  keys <<- values <<- NULL
  insert <- function(key, value) {
    temp <- c(keys, key)
    ord <- order(temp)
    keys <<- temp[ord]
    values <<- c(values, list(value))[ord]
  }
  pop <- function() {
    head <- values[[1]]
    values <<- values[-1]
    keys <<- keys[-1]
    return(head)
  }
  empty <- function() length(keys) == 0
  list(insert = insert, pop = pop, empty = empty)
}
```

Comment: Comparing this implementation with the `collections` implementation the highest priority is given with the lowest number.  To make this work as `collections::collections::priority_queue()` you have to use `ord <- order(temp, decreasing=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the package collections: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collections/index.html

```
q <- PriorityQueue()
q$push("not_urgent")
q$push("urgent", priority = 2)
q$push("not_as_urgent", priority = 1)
q$pop() # urgent
q$pop() # not_as_urgent
q$pop() # not_urgent
```

EDIT: update syntax for collection v0.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You could probably create this quite easily yourself, either using classes (Reference classes fit best), or using a `data.frame` with a custom type, combined with some functions that operate on it (`add_to_queue(element, queue_object, priority)`, `get_item(queue_object)`). These functions would be the methods in case of the reference class. I like the reference class solution better as it stores both the state and the logic in one place.